# I am getting "java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero" when I run my program

Tags: java

Hello I am learning Java and I am trying to get 3 images that are 300x300, 600x600, and 900x900 pixels and scramble it by splitting the image into a 3X3 grid and then mixing each 3x3 square in that image to generate a random mix every time I run my program. I decided to do it by putting all the pixels into an array and then scrambling that image where  the length /3 gives me a remainder of 0. However I am getting the error "java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero". Can someone help me fix my problem please.

```
public void randomPictureShift(Picture scrambledImage){
Pixel blankImage [] = this.getPixels();
 Pixel originalImage [] = scrambledImage.getPixels();

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Random r = new Random();
for (int i = originalImage.length; i > 0; i--) {
  int index = r.nextInt(i);
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  if ((i)%(1/3) == 0){
    //swap
    Pixel tmp = originalImage[index];
    originalImage[index] = originalImage[i];
    originalImage[i] = tmp;
```

Comment: `(i)%(1/3)` is the same as `(i)%(0)`, which is probably what's causing the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%(1/3)` is equivalent to `%0`, which is division by zero. What you want is testing if the length is divisable by three, you you can simply write

```
if (i % 3 == 0) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you divide two integers:

(i)%(1/3) === i % 0 which is dividing by zero

To fix it you can do: (i)%(1.0/3.0)
or:                   (i)%3